# Translation of old VB6 QBColor function into C#

Tags: c#, vb6, colors

I am rewriting a VB6 program in C# and the VB program uses the `QBColor` function

At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2dz8078(v=VS.80).aspx it states which number is equal to which colour.

Furthermore, on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc1dyw8b(v=VS.80).aspx it says that `Blue` (according to Microsoft) is `0,0,255` (no objection really). But what is the then the difference between `Blue` and `LightBlue`?
Those two pages can not mean the same colour when they talk about blue?

Does anyone have the RGB translation table of the colours for `QBColor`? I would suspect that

`QBColor(1)` `Blue` is equal to `RGB(0,0,128)`

`QBColor(9)` `LightBlue` is equal to `RGB(0,0,255)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. Blue is (0,0,128).
Here is the code to go from QBColor to RGB:

Dim Color As Integer
        Color = 1
        Console.WriteLine(&HFF& And QBColor(Color))
        Console.WriteLine((&HFF00& And QBColor(Color)) \ 256)
        Console.WriteLine((&HFF0000 And QBColor(Color)) \ 65536)

You can easily put it in a loop to check all the values.

Answer (score 2):

`QBColor` is included in the .Net framework, so you could just use `QBColor` in your C# program. Just reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic`.

Comment: Seems a bit over the top for essentially an array index though.

Comment: @Deanna Isn't it a bit over the top to reimplement a function that already exists in the framework?? You can reference another namespace in a couple of mouse clicks.

Comment: If I was writing VB.net, Maybe. I changed the colours (and number available) later though.